# Difference between Windows XP and Win 7 in DLL loading with manifest file

Tags: visual-c++, manifest, dll

I am using a .Net 4 component that creates an Activation Context (via interop) using a .manifest file in a sub-directory.

`AppDir`

```
- App.exe (.Net 4)
- App.dll (.Net 4)
---- SubDir
-------- lib.dll (Native x86)
------- lib.manifest
```

```
    activationContext = new NativeMethods.ACTCTX();
    activationContext.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(NativeMethods.ACTCTX));
    activationContext.lpSource = this.ManifestFileName;
    activationContext.dwFlags = 4;
    activationContext.lpAssemblyDirectory = new System.IO.FileInfo(this.ManifestFileName).Directory.FullName;
    contextHandle = NativeMethods.CreateActCtx(ref activationContext);
    int winError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
```

Current directory = AppDir

Manifest path = .\SubDir\lib.manifest

In Win 7 SubDir/lib.dll is loaded and executes fine.

In Win XP manifest file is loaded fine but system then tries to load AppDir/lib.dll, not AppDir/SubDir/lib.dll

I've verified this via ProcMon.
If I copy everything from SubDir into AppDir and point to AppDir/lib.manifest, it works fine in XP i.e. current directory.

What do I need to do to make XP load lib.dll in SubDir?

Comment: Setting lpAssemblyDirectory results in an error in Win7, so I removed it since it didn't make a difference in Win XP anyway.